A question about Durrett's triangular array WLLNs
I'm reading Durrett 2.2.2-2.2.3, which presents a few weak law of large numbers for triangular arrays(see the screen scratch below)


Both states that the sum of $n$ independent (not necessarily identically distributed) random variables substracting the mean of the sum (or mean of truncated sum) and divided by $b_n$ converges to 0 in probability. Although both statements are valid, I'm wondering why these results are presented in the way they are. Because in both theorems, I could set $b_n$ to be a sequence that diverges to infinity at an extremely fast rate, which will of course set $\frac{S_n-\mu_n}{b_n}$ and $\frac{S_n-a_n}{b_n}$ to converge to zero in probability. Then these two results seem not very useful. This is unlike the usual statement of WLLN for triangular arrays, in which $b_n=n$.

The law of large numbers is proved using Kronecker's lemma, which is (I am guessing) why the theorem is stated like this.

@Andrew Thank you very much!

This is useful because it is true for any sequence of $b_n$ satisfying the conditions (of course it's pointless for very fast convergin to infinity $b_n$s but you can choose a much slower sequence).
